# Error when executing a linux script by ansible

Tags: ansible

I try to run a linux script with the shell module but I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: sh: command not found.
```

To run this linux script, I need to run it with a different user (oracle) than the one I use to connect

This is the task of the playbook

```
    - name: Execute
      become: true
      become_user: oracle
      become_method: sudo
      shell: sh ora_expdp_partition.sh P_05_2021
      args:
        chdir: /fuentes01/vasmonitor
      environment:
        ORACLE_BASE: /oracle/oracle/app/oracle
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /oracle/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64
        ORACLE_HOME: /oracle/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
        PATH: /usr/sbin:/oracle/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/local/bin
        CLASSPATH: /oracle/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/jlib:/oracle/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/jlib
```

In the task I need to execute the script with the user oracle
When I execute the script with the user oracle manually, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `environment` you specify a `PATH` that does not include `/bin` (or `/usr/bin`), so `sh` is not found in the `PATH`.